# Reproduce animation from PowerPoint with LaTeX

Tags: beamer, animations, powerpoint

Is there any way to reproduce [this](https://github.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/blob/master/Introduction.pptx?raw=true) PowerPoint animation in LaTeX? I also produced this [video](https://github.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/blob/master/Introduction.mp4?raw=true).

I got to that point:

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Beamer Example}
\author{Author}
\subject{Presentation Programs} 
\institute[ University]{
    Department of XZ\\
    University}        

%% you need these
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}        
    \section{Outline}               
    \frame[label=exampleframe]{
        \frametitle{Example}                
        %\faPlane            
    }           

\begin{frame}[c]

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{10} 
    \multiframe{10}{iPosition=0+2}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %\node[circle,draw=black] (t1) at (-5,0) {};
        \node[text width=6cm] (tx1) at (\iPosition,0) {Teacher: Name};
        \node[text width=6cm] (tx2) at (\iPosition,-0.6) {Introduction To Latex};
        \node[text width=6cm] (tx3) at (\iPosition,-1.2) {Class 1};
        \node[text width=6cm] (tx4) at (\iPosition,-1.8) {Be Welcome!!!};
        %\draw[-]  (t1.center) -- (tx.center);
        \node[text width=6cm] (t21) at (5,0) {};
        \node[text width=6cm] (t22) at (5,-0.6) {};
        \node[text width=6cm] (t23) at (5,-1.2) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \multiframe{10}{iPos=-5+0}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[text width=8cm] (UFV) at (-5,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{download.png}};
    \node[text width=8cm] (t3) at (-5,0) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I would like to try to reproduce as close as possible!

The code is also on that [link (Overleaf).](https://www.overleaf.com/2258595951rbgzdttbmfvg)

Comment: Exist the `beamer` package.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes of course! I want to play the animation on the beamer! You know how?

Comment: Can you post a screen-cast of the running animation? (Cannot read pptx here.)

Comment: @fsbmat For my humble opinion your question it is a bit off-topic.

Comment: @Sebastiano I'm going to give an online course on latex and I would like to do this animation. I don't know how to do it and I don't know where to ask!

Comment: You might find the animate package useful http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/macros/latex/contrib/animate/animate.pdf

Comment: @fsbmat If time is short you could use LaTeX tools that are integrated with power point...for example IguanaTeX to write your slide with the Computern Modern font. And for the animation to can use the palette motion of Power Point. Here some important links: http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LC6SYNlTOOI; https://www.fast.ai/2019/06/17/latex-ppt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve, follow the code if it is in someone's interest:

```
\documentclass[standalone]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Singapore}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\title{Beamer Example}
\author{Author}
\subject{Presentation Programs} 
\institute[ University]{
    Department of XZ\\
    University}        

%% you need these
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}
\usepackage{animate}
%\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\newtcolorbox{shadedbox}{
  drop shadow southeast,
  breakable,
  enhanced jigsaw,
  colback=white,
}




\begin{document}        
    \section{Outline}               
    \frame[label=exampleframe]{
        \frametitle{Example}                
        %\faPlane            
    }           

\begin{frame}[c]



\begin{animateinline}[autoplay]{10} 
    \multiframe{10}{iPosition=-5+1}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[text width=8cm] (UFV) at (-3,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{download.png}};
        %\node[circle,draw=black] (t1) at (-5,0) {};
        \node[text width=5cm] (tx1) at (\iPosition,0) {\begin{shadedbox}
        Teacher: Name\\
        Introduction To Latex\\
        Class 1\\
        Be Welcome
        \end{shadedbox}};
        \node[text width=5cm] (t2) at (1,0) {};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}



\end{document}
```